# Discord.py, Is it possible to run a task every 1 hour?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that counts the number of online members in a guild every 1 hour. Then, it finds the average "activity" of the server. The problem is that I don't know how to run the "counting task" every 1 hour or so. This is what I ve got so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def d(ctx):
    memList = []
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.status == discord.Status.offline:
            memList.append(user.id)

    total = len(memList)
    print(total)
```

This code counts the members^

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=3600)
async def f(ctx):
    memList = []
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.status == discord.Status.offline:
            memList.append(user.id)

    total = len(memList)
    print(total)

f.start()
```

This is supposed to count the members every 1 hour, however, I don't have a way to pass the context for this peace of code:
`for user in ctx.guild.members:`

Comment: Please change the title, it doesn't describe your question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to remember that your bot isn't 'smart' enough to know where `ctx` comes from if you don't pass it through your `f.start()` loop. Either way, you shouldn't pass `ctx` into your loop, as your bot would be connected to multiple servers, so how will your bot know which server will be your `ctx.guild`?

Instead, my recommendation is to create your own guild object through [`bot.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) and iterate the members through there. Do view the revised code below.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=1) # alternatively, minutes=60, seconds=3600, etc.
async def f():
    memList = []
    guild = bot.get_guild(your_guild_id) # replace this with your server's id
    for user in guild.members:
        if user.status == discord.Status.offline:
            memList.append(user.id)

    total = len(memList)
    print(total)

f.start()
```